# Acrobat Javascript: How to convert attached image to icon?

Tags: javascript, dialog, adobe, acrobat, imageicon

My goal is it to have a script for a image popup.
For that I use the javascript dialog with an icon.
After converting a 1000px Image to aRGB-String
I've got the message:

```
Acrobat 10.0 - Integrierte Escript-Funktionen
Adobe Acrobat SOAP 10.0

InternalError: script stack space quota is exhausted
```

Also the PDF file size rises up to 13MB.
So my question is: Is it possible to convert attached Images to an icon by using javascript?
Or what will be the best practice?

Best Regards

Markus

Comment: You don't want to use JavaScript for image conversion. JS was not built to handle that, and will be extremely slow in doing so, if it's possible in the first place.

Comment: Ok. But having the images hex encoded will explode the filesize. So what do you recommand?